# SSH into WSL from Raspberry Pi

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a windows 10 machine running WSL (ubuntu) and a Raspberry Pi. I'm able to ssh into the RPi from WSL without a problem, and I'm able to use `putty` to ssh into WSL while all the Windows machine (following [this](https://blog.netsarang.com/1884/using-the-linux-subsystem-in-windows-10/)  worked ). But I am unable to ssh from the RPi to WSL.

I'm getting the IP for WSL by `hostname -I` (from within WSL), and attempting to ssh from the RPi with a command like `ssh user@xxx.xxx.xx.x`, but it can't seem to connect and just hangs. I've looked at every top hit for every version of "ssh into wsl" I could find without luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Windows has an SSH server built in these days; do you need to run one inside WSL, or just connect to the machine (whence you can go immediately into WSL if you want)?

Comment: Really, I would like to be able to stream data from my raspberry pi to my windows machine which has a lot more disk space. If I can make use of window's own ssh server, that would be fine - I just don't understand why the rpi can't "see" the WSL ip. does that make sense?